# Secondary citation MS Word 2013 (APA Style)

Tags: citations

I can't believe I can't find an answer in Google for this. I need to insert a secondary citation like this

> AuthorX 2013 (as quoted in AuthorY, 2010)

The closest answer I could find was editing the field and referencing the secondary author by tag with an '\m' switch but that cuts the whole thing too short.

Answer (score 1):

googled switch codes and used the '\s' suffix tag. Problem solved